# iPhone(4s): How to update the application with apple-certificated ID

Tags: ios, xcode

with the Apple-certificated ID , we can debug/test the application on the real iPhone and Xcode is always used to install the application to be tested .

My question is : without the xcode, how can I install the test application on real iPhone.

PLease help to enlighten me . 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: what have you tried already? there is loads of documentation on _ad hoc_ deployment.

Comment: Sorry to the postponed comments on it because of little opportunity of accessing internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either send the app and a provisioning profile to a user who can then install the app using iTunes.

Or, and my preferred choice, use a service such as [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com) to share your app over the air with testers and/or clients.

Comment: One more question , can I use Windows + latest iTune + bin files + signed file to install it ?